# Android Speech bubble is outside the activity

Tags: java, android

The Speechbubble is in the outside, but if I remove the picture it is work perfectly. What is wrong? Sorry for my bad english, I hope you can understand the bug.

This is a screenshot (the speechbubble must have a margin from left).

[image]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:emojicon="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    tools:ignore="contentDescription" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:background="@drawable/bubble"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:linksClickable="true"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="chat_right_textchat_right_textchat_right_textchat_right_text"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            emojicon:emojiconSize="24dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="@drawable/picture"
            android:gravity="right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to change the `LinearLayout` that contains the Bubble to take up the remaining width instead of using `wrap_content` for the width. You can do this by setting the `layout_weight` to 1 and the `layout_width` to 0dp:

```
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
```

Another thing to note is that as the layout currently is you don't need the inner `LinearLayouts` at all and can use the bubble background on the `TextView`, this will simplify the layout as well as improve performance slightly.

Comment: Now the Speechbubble width is 100%, but it must be wrap_content.

Comment: Then have you tried just adding `layout_weight="1"` and keeping your `layout_width="wrap_content"`?

Comment: You can't have it both ways unfortunately, if you use wrap_content the content is too big to fit so it will go beyond the bounds of the view like before, whilst if you set it to take up the remaining space as above it will do the best it can with the space it has, the text will just create more lines

Comment: What about when your app goes on larger devices, the left margin will be considerably larger than the right. Can I ask why you don't want to use the layout_weight method?